# An established connection was aborted by the software in host machine

Tags: c#, sockets, connection

I couldn't find my answer in some topics.
I have a client/server code.
I have a client side and server side in a separate programs .
This is client side:

```
 try
        {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        string text = "";
        text = uitbtextmsg.Text;
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        int bytesSent = User.Send(msg);
        int bytesRec = User.Receive(bytes);

        uirtbmsg.Text = uirtbmsg.Text + '\n' + " " + text;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
```

This is for when I am connected to server and I want to chat with that socket.
This is my connection:

```
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[2];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
            Socket User = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            User.Connect(remoteEP);
```

And this is server side:

```
 byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[2];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10000);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    TextRecieved = data;
                    Thread textbox = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteInReachTextBox));
                    textbox.Start();
                    break;
                }

                //uirtbreport.Text = data;
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                handler.Send(msg);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

When client first sends a message to server  this procedure is ok! But when it send another message it will throw an Exception:

> System.Net.Socket.SocketException(0x80004005):An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer)\r\n   at
>   Client.Form1.uibtnsendmsg_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're breaking the while loop (look my comment)

```
while (true)
{
    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
    data = null;

    while (true)
    {
        bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
        TextRecieved = data;
        Thread textbox = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteInReachTextBox));
        textbox.Start();

        // -----------> HERE!!!!!!

        break;
    }

    //uirtbreport.Text = data;
    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    handler.Send(msg);
    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    handler.Close();
}
```

Why do you create a thread within the 'broken' loop?

**Also, don't forget this is a streaming socket, which means that 'packets' can be sent as one buffer or split into multiple 'packets'.**

Comment: I was creating a thread to print the client Request. because server was busy for accepting .now i thing just one client can speak to the server.is that correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. If you want to have multiple clients, you should use multi threading. Put the `Socket handler = listener.Accept();` within a while loop and pass it's result _(Socket)_ to a thread that start receiving on that socket.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what textbox.Start() does, but it seems to me that after the server reads some data from the client, it **breaks** out of the "while (true)" and closes the socket connection. 
This is why you are only able to send a single message.

```
Socket handler = listener.Accept();
...
while (true)
{
    .... read data
    textbox.Start();
    break;
}

/* Here you close the connection */
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
handler.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want a persistent tcp connection on same socket.

Just don't break the loop not to shutdown the socket.